# Wordpress.com how are 'related posts' determined?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

Wordpress.com allows inclusion of 'related posts' below each post.

How does it choose which posts to display - by matching category, tag, or both?

Comment: Through the power of elastic search and some secret sauce they don't share. If you want to replicate it, there's a Jetpack module for that, it uses the same system, but for specifics you're best asking their support or technical docs, the internals of wp.com aren't known by most here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that related posts have similar tags, at least according to this article, which includes code for a query that will include related posts: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-related-posts-in-wordpress/

Couldn't find anything about related posts in a quick look in the Codex.